# ¿Cómo devolver un arreglo de promesas?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando de armar un file tree view. Utilizando la librería fs de node y la librería bluebird para volver asincronos los metodos que tienen callback dentro de la librería fs, llegué a esta función:

```
const generarObjeto = directorio => {  
return fs.readdirAsync(directorio)
  .then(arregloDeNombres => {
    const promesasDeArchivos = arregloDeNombres.map(nombreDelArchivo => {
      const rutaCompleta = `${directorio}/${nombreDelArchivo}`;
      return fs.statAsync(rutaCompleta)
        .then(infoArchivo => {
          const archivo = {};
          archivo.rutaDelArchivo = rutaCompleta;
          archivo.esArchivo = infoArchivo.isFile();
          if (!archivo.esArchivo) {
            return generateFileTreeObject(archivo.rutaDelArchivo)
              .then(otrosNombresDeArchivos => {
                archivo.files = otrosNombresDeArchivos;
              })
              .catch(console.error);
          }
          return archivo;
        });
    });
    console.log(promesasDeArchivos);
    return Promise.all(promesasDeArchivos);
  });
};
```

Todo funciona muy bien, sin embargo al final de la función, podemos ver que hago un console.log de "promesasDeArchivos" y estos vienen vacíos de la siguiente manera:

```
[ Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined } ]
[ Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined } ]
```

Esta variable debería de llenarse con los valores que tiene la otra variable que se llama archivo, como lo podemos ver en el return, esa variable tiene valores, pero por algún motivo no se pasan a la otra. Ya le di vuelta a esto y no encuentro el error.

Gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

EDICIÓN:

Cambié un poco el código para hacer debug, después de la declaración del "rutaComplete", en lugar de retornar de un solo, declaré otra variable y le asigne el valor del "fs.statAsync" e hice un console log del resultado y desde ahí va vacío, he ahi el motivo por el cual "promesasDeArchivos" viene vacío, sin embargo no logro entender el motivo por el cuál sucede eso, si como podemos ver, hago el return en cada iteración y al hacer debug, la variable archivo tiene valor al hacer el return.

Answer (score 0):

Segun veo en tu código el posible error que veo es que no devuelves el 'archivo' cuando utilizas la promise 'generateFileTreeObject', ya que al no devolver no retornas el valor y por eso te aparece 'undefined'.

Te paso el código con la posible solucion:

```
const generarObjeto = directorio => {
return fs.readdirAsync(directorio)
    .then(arregloDeNombres => {
        const promesasDeArchivos = arregloDeNombres.map(nombreDelArchivo => {
            const rutaCompleta = `${directorio}/${nombreDelArchivo}`;
            return fs.statAsync(rutaCompleta)
                .then(infoArchivo => {
                    const archivo = {};
                    archivo.rutaDelArchivo = rutaCompleta;
                    archivo.esArchivo = infoArchivo.isFile();
                    if (!archivo.esArchivo) {
                        return generateFileTreeObject(archivo.rutaDelArchivo)
                            .then(otrosNombresDeArchivos => {
                                archivo.files = otrosNombresDeArchivos;
                                return archivo // --> Esto es lo que faltaba
                            })
                            .catch(console.error);
                    }
                    return archivo;
                })
                .catch(console.error)// --> Controlar el posible error
        });
        console.log(promesasDeArchivos);
        return Promise.all(promesasDeArchivos);
    })
    .catch(console.error)// --> Controlar el posible error

};
```

Espero que esta solución te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola amigo, te cuento que probé lo que me dijiste y sigo con el mismo problema, si te fijas el return de archivo esta justo después de ese if

Comment: Hola Alex, es verdad que retornas el 'archivo' después pero si te fijas tu retornas  'generateFileTreeObject' por lo que no retornaría el archivo como dices, sino que tendrías que retornarlo como te comento.
¿Puedes añadir '.catch(console.error)' en los 'then' que tienes por sí hay un error que no estamos controlando? (te edito el código para que sepas a lo que me refiero)